# Is there a better way to check child params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Is there a better way to check for items_attributes than the following code? I have to check params[:order] first since sometimes that may not exist, but I hate the look of the long conditional.

```
if params[:order] and params[:order][:items_attributes]
```

**UPDATE** for ruby 2.3, now you can use the dig method

```
params.dig(:order, :item_attributes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper method for easier work with nested hashes. Create ruby_ext.rb file in your lib folder, and write this function:

```
module RubyExt
  module SafeHashChain
    def safe(*args)
      if args.size == 0 then self # Called without args ...
      elsif args.size == 1 then self[args[0]] # Reached end
      elsif self[args[0]].is_a?(Hash) then self[args[0]].safe(*args[1..-1])
      else nil end # Reached end-value too soon
    end
  end
end

class Hash; include RubyExt::SafeHashChain; end
```

After this you can call safe method on nested hashes like this:

```
params.safe(:order,:items_attributes)
```

It will return value from items_attributes. If order or items_attributes don`t exist it will return nil.

Comment: I like your idea of extending in 1 place so I dont have to write additional code in every controller or view. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [andand gem](https://github.com/raganwald/andand):

```
if params[:order].andand[:items_attributes]
```

You could also use `try`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try`, like so:

```
params[:order].try(:[], :items_attributes)
```

The try method returns `nil` if the receiver does not respond to it, instead of raising an exception.

Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If I have such problem I would think about extending basic ruby class `Hash` with something like this (this is just an idea)

```
class Hash

  def has_nested_values?(*args)
    current_value = self.dup
    args.each do |arg|
      current_value = current_value[arg]
      break unless current_value
    end
    !!current_value
  end

end
```

and the result is

```
h[:a] = {b: {c: {d: 1}}}

h.has_nested_values?(:a, :b, :c)
=> true

h.has_nested_values?(:a, :b, :cc)
=> false
```

PS I don't like `dup` in implementation but it works

Answer (score 0):

Params is actually an instance of [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) and has built in white list filtering features.

This makes it possible to do stuff like this:

```
# White list for Order params
def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:items_attributes)
end

// If :order is missing exception, and then filter only permitted.
valid_params = order_params()

// Also make these calls safe without risk for unwanted params
order = Order.new(order_params())
order.save!
```

Comment: I do favor this approach when I have multiple child params, especially for creating or updating, but sometimes I just want to just check one or I want to do this in the view file. I find the params.require to be the almost the same amount of code and not that much clearer when just checking one param.

Answer (score 0):

You'll may like fetch with a default?

```rb
order = params.fetch(:order, {})

if order[:item_attributes]
  # ...
end
```